# Find and replace pairs of $$ and $$ with \[ and \] in a LaTeX file

Tags: latex

I'm working on editing an old LaTeX file, where the beginning and ending of display math mode is denoted with the outdated pairs of `$$` and `$$`, rather than the modern convention of `\[` and `\]`. (See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for an explanation of why usings pairs of `$$` and `$$` is deprecated.) My LaTeX editor has a simple find and replace function, but the problem is that I want to replace every first instance of `$$` with `\[` and every second instance of `$$` with `\]`. I'm not very familiar with programming so I was wondering if there was a simple language I could code this text replacement program in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions should work: Find `\$\$(.+?)\$\$` and replace with `\[$1\]` or `\[\1\]` depending on which text editor you use. Most text editors have this functionality built-in. Note that this is a naïve replacement and may fail on edge cases such as literal `$$`s.